# Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function wp_redirect()

Tags: php, wordpress

I've started to create some part of my plugin. In the class I will start with an redirect. I want to use the wp_redirect function but get the Error above. My code until now is:

```php
class nms_bookmark {
  public function __construct()
  {
    if(isset($_REQUEST['nms_oa_uid']) && $_REQUEST['nms_oa_uid'] != ''):
      $this->nms_bookmark_start();
    endif;
  }
  public function nms_bookmark_start()
  {
    wp_redirect( 'https://www.myside.de/' );
    exit;
  }
}
```

Thx for your help!

Comment: I've indeted you code and enabled syntax highlighting. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274371/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work